# Error running PuppyCrawl's Maven Checkstyle Plugin

Tags: maven, checkstyle, google-style-guide

Well, I'm trying to configure Maven's Checkstyle Plugin on the project I'm currently working on and I'm getting the following:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0:check (verify-style) on project email: Failed during checkstyle execution: Failed during checkstyle configuration: unable to parse configuration stream: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
```

So, running `mvn install -X` I've got the following stacktrace:

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
        ... 52 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
        ... 58 more
```

It seems to be related to the DTD specified on the google-checks.xml I've found on the following link on Github: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
          "-//Checkstyle//DTD Checkstyle Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">
```

I've tried to add that certificate to my JVM truststore but it doesn't work.
Can anybody figure out what's going wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please share complete maven config to let us see all details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml

Please use the configuration DTD for your version of Checkstyle that you are using. `master` is where current development is taking place. As we are changing and adding new things in master, the release versions of Checkstyle may not support it and end up with exceptions.

Here is an example Google XML for release 8.10.1: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/checkstyle-8.10.1/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml